# Python: [(x, y) for (x, y) in list_of_tuples if f(x) is not empty]

Tags: python, tuples, filtering, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples in the following format:

```
input_list = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ... , (xn, yn)]
```

I want to transform this list into a different one by applying a function on the first parameter in each tuple, and storing that in a different list of tuples. So:

```
new_list = [(func(x), y) for (x, y) in input_list]
```

The thing is, `func(x)` may return an empty string. In that case, I do not want the tuple `(func(x), y)` to be in `new_list`. I expect that I could do something like:

```
new_list = [(func(x), y) for (x, y) in input_list if func(x)]
```

But this would cause double the computation and would be terribly inefficient. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: `[(x,y) for (x,y) in [(func(x), y) for (x, y) in list] if x]` ?

Comment: @fredtantini what I was thinking - just turn the list-comp into a gen-exp instead...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* just use a regular `for` loop:

```
new_list = []
for x, y in input_list:
    result = func(x)
    if result:
        new_list.append((result, y))
```

If you are insisting on a one-liner list comprehension you could use:

```
[(res, y) for x, y in input_list for res in (func(x),) if res]
```

where a nested loop over a single-element tuple gives you a reference to the function output. However, that'll require another 3 lines of comment explaining to future maintainers what the hell you are pulling there, and thus the explicit loop is (in my opinion) the better option here.

A third option is to embed a generator expression transforming the inputs first:

```
[(res, y) for res, y in ((func(x), y) for x, y in input_list) if res]
```

which again may require a cognitive leap for maintainers that may not be worth it.

Comment: Wow...that was eerie.  :)  Obviously I have to upvote your solution now.

Comment: Things like these remind me that I'm not a great programmer until I am able to just say "I could just use a normal `for` loop!". Thank you for the detailed and informative answer!

Answer (score 5):

Do it in two steps. No need to build an intermediate list, a generator expression is enough:

```
computed_values = ((func(x), y) for (x, y) in list)
filtered_values = [(x, y) for (x, y) in computed_values if x != '']
```

Comment: This was a possible approach, but I wanted to avoid having to filter the list after already transforming it.

Comment: @user991710: but the transformation happens *as you iterate over the generator expression*. It achieves the same effect as all 3 approaches I named in my answer, the last of which is essentially the same as this one but with `computed_values` inlined.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, it seems I misunderstood his answer then. Thank you  for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

```
new_list = []
for (x, y) in old_list:
  new_x = func(x)
  if new_x: new_list.append((new_x, y))
```